# "I am 25 from the USA."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, conjunctions

1. Should there be an "and" between "25 and from", and why? Please explain the rules.
2. Do the following sentences work, and why?

- I am 25, from the USA.
- I am 25 from the USA.
- I am 25 and I am from the USA.

Comment: In  your language, you would not use an "and" there?

Comment: You're asking multiple questions. That's not cool. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

What we essentially have is a list. It is normal to insert "and" before the last item of a list or between the items if there are only two. But in casual speech.  The speaker will assume you will mentally insert the implied subject. This is an example of parallelism.

It is quite common to have

> The cat is happy, on the mat [and,] eating a fish.

We understand that each of the three complementary phrases apply to "the cat".

The commas do help, and would help in your example too. "I'm 25, from the US". List items are generally separated by commas.

It would be correct to insert "and"  "I'm 25 and from the US"

It would also be correct to express this as two sentences. "I'm 25, and I'm from the US".

Comment: Just to add a bit to your answer, the sentence "I am 25 from the USA" sounds like your name is "25".   For example, a good sentence is, "I am 007 from the UK."

Comment: @James K, thank you. 1. So, the correct version should have an "and" and why?     2. Is the comma between "25" and "from" right or wrong and why?0

Comment: You can think of this as a list of things.  The commas help,  "and" would be good before the last item. But neither is strictly necessary, because there is little chance of misunderstanding without them.

Comment: @James K, okay so either even without "and" or "," between "25" and "from" is still correct and okay?

Comment: You seem to want a legal ruling.  I'd prefer "... and from ..." but you will hear this kind of spoken phrase quite often.  The answer  to "is it okay?" will depend on whether I am speaking (in which case there are no commas, but there might be intonal clues) or writing a letter, or writing a resume.